# ERC error EAGLE

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, eaglecad

I do not understand why I am getting and error for the POWER pin IC2 and IC3, I have attached Vcc+ to + and Vcc- to -.

What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: You get a warning, not an error. What warning is not shown clearly in the screen shots. Looks like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/why-do-i-get-warnings-for-all-my-voltage-supply-connections-in-eagle-cad

Comment: First off, it's a warning not an error. Did you set the Pin Type to a power pin?

Comment: Yes looks like it Huisman.

Comment: I do not know how to set it to power pin. I just want to supply a Vcc + and - after the decoupling

Comment: I am not familiar with Eagle, some quick internet searching should get you an answer.